# applet not installing when using javacardx.framework.math.BigNumber

Tags: applet, smartcard, javacard, jcop

I've encountered a problem while declaring a BigNumber datatype in my javacard applet. The applet loads properly into the simulator if i just comment the declaration. The problem to be precise is while loading the import.cap file
(jcshell: Error code: 6a80 (Wrong data))

java card kit 2.2.2 using

```
  import javacard.framework.APDU;
  import javacard.framework.Applet;
  import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
  import javacard.framework.ISOException;
  import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
  import javacardx.framework.math.BigNumber;

 public class LargeBal extends Applet {

 // CLA byte
public static final byte BANK_CLA = (byte) 0x80;

// INS byte
public static final byte INS_GET_BALANCE = 0X02;
public static final byte INS_CREDIT = 0X04;
public static final byte INS_DEBIT = 0X06;

/**
 * SW bytes for Arithmetic exception
 */
final static short INVALID_NUMBER_FORMAT = 0x6308;

/**
 * Initial account balance
 */
final static byte[] INITIAL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE = { (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00,
        (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };

// Amount of money in user's account

private BigNumber accountBalance;

// Big number for temporary calculation
BigNumber tempBigNum;

// temporary buffer used as scratch space

byte[] scratchSpace;

private LargeBal() {

     accountBalance = new BigNumber((byte) 8);

    // initialize account balance to 100,000.00
     accountBalance.init(INITIAL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE, (byte) 0,
     (byte) INITIAL_ACCOUNT_BALANCE.length, BigNumber.FORMAT_BCD);

    // initialize the temporary big number
     tempBigNum = new BigNumber(BigNumber.getMaxBytesSupported());

    // initialize the scratchSpace
    scratchSpace = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 10,
            JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
    register();
}

public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
    // GP-compliant JavaCard applet registration
    new LargeBal();
}

public void process(APDU apdu) {
    // Good practice: Return 9000 on SELECT
    if (selectingApplet()) {
        return;
    }

    byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
    switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS]) {
    case INS_GET_BALANCE:
         getBalance(apdu, buf);
        break;
    case INS_CREDIT:

        break;
    case INS_DEBIT:

        break;
    default:
        // good practice: If you don't know the INStruction, say so:
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
}

private void getBalance(APDU apdu, byte[] buffer) {

    if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] == BigNumber.FORMAT_BCD) {
        accountBalance.toBytes(buffer, (short) 0, (short) 8,
                BigNumber.FORMAT_BCD);
    } else if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] == BigNumber.FORMAT_HEX) {
        accountBalance.toBytes(buffer, (short) 0, (short) 8,
                BigNumber.FORMAT_HEX);
    } else
        ISOException.throwIt(INVALID_NUMBER_FORMAT);

    apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, (short) 8);
}
```

}

Comment: Would you please add installation process output also? Are you sure your card is Java Card 2.2.2 compatible?

Comment: @Abraham I am working on jcop simulator and it is java card 2.2.2 compatible.cap file is created.
Header.cap loaded,
Directory.cap loaded,
loading Import.cap is failed. status: Wrong data.
jcshell: Error code: 6a80 (Wrong data)
jcshell: Wrong response APDU: 6A80

Comment: I loaded your program on NetBeans simulator successfully! And it works fine. So, as Mr.Roland mentioned in his answer, I think it is something related to your simulator/card compatibility with the math library package.

Comment: I think Michael's answer is the right answer. So you can check it using the "v" mark beside the question.

Answer (score 5):

`javacardx.framework.math` is an *optional* package. Thus, not all cards/emulators implement this. In your case, it seems that the card does not implement `javacardx.framework.math.BigNumber`. Consequently it refuses to load/install the applet.

From the *Runtime Environment Specification*, Java Card Platform, Version 2.2.2 (section 9.7):

> #### Optional Extension Packages
>
> Some API packages in the Java Card technology are designated as extension
>   packages and may be optionally supported by an implementation. But, if supported,
>   all the classes in the package and its subpackages must be implemented by the
>   platform and reside on the card.
>
> The following are optional Java Card technology extension packages:
>
> - `javacardx.apdu` *[...]*
> - `javacardx.biometry` *[...]*
> - `javacardx.crypto` *[...]*
> - `javacardx.external` *[...]*
> - `javacardx.framework` *[...]* If implemented, this package must include all the contained subpackages - `util`, `math`, and `tlv`.

Comment: Is `if (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1] == BigNumber.FORMAT_BCD)` a correct expression? I think in the left he has a `byte` type value, and in the right it is not, right? What is the meaning of this line?

Comment: @Abraham Comparing a byte to a byte is a perfectly valid expression (`buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]` is of type `byte` and `FORMAT_BCD` is defined as `public static final` **`byte`** `FORMAT_BCD = 1`).

Comment: @MichaelRoland Do you have any information to check which optional packages works with card/emulators.

Comment: No, I suggest that you request such information directly from the card/chip/OS manufacturer.

Comment: @MichaelRoland Where in the JavaCard 2.2 specs are the optional packages listed? I'm trying to find documentation to confirm that javacardfx.framework.math is actually marked as optional by Oracle/Sun, and not just frequently left out. I didn't find anything in the JCVM spec, which seems to describe other optional components such as the `int` type and garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks! I was searching for BigNumber (and other classes) in the documentation instead of searching for the package name.